# Minimax function for chess engine in python cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, chess, minimax

I am trying to build a simple chess engine in python using the chess package. My minimax function is buggy and breaks atm. My code below...

```
# import package
import chess

# define starting params
board = chess.Board()
depth = 3
alpha = -1000000
beta = 1000000
player = True

# board evaluation
def boardEval(board):
    wp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.WHITE))
    bp = len(board.pieces(chess.PAWN, chess.BLACK))
    wn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.WHITE))
    bn = len(board.pieces(chess.KNIGHT, chess.BLACK))
    wb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.WHITE))
    bb = len(board.pieces(chess.BISHOP, chess.BLACK))
    wr = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.WHITE))
    br = len(board.pieces(chess.ROOK, chess.BLACK))
    wq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.WHITE))
    bq = len(board.pieces(chess.QUEEN, chess.BLACK))
    return (wp-bp) + 3 * (wn-bn) + 3 * (wb-bb) - 5 * (wr-br) + 10 * (wq-bq)


# minimax function
def minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, player):
    # check whether game is complete
    gameComplete = board.is_game_over()
    bestMove = None
    moves = [str(l) for l in board.legal_moves]
    tempBoard = board.copy()
    
    if depth == 0:
        return boardEval(tempBoard), bestMove
    if gameComplete:
        print('Game completed')
        return None

    for move in  moves:
        m = chess.Move.from_uci(move)
        tempBoard.push(m)
        
        if player:
            maxEval = -1000000
            value, bestMove = minimax(tempBoard, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)
            if maxEval < value:
                maxEval = value
                bestMove = move
            alpha = alpha if alpha > value else value
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
            return maxEval, bestMove
        else:
            minEval = 1000000
            value, bestMove = minimax(tempBoard, depth - 1, alpha, beta, True)
            if minEval < value:
                minEval = value
                bestMove = move
            beta = beta if beta < value else value
            if beta <= alpha:
                break
            return minEval, bestMove
       
# find best move
minimax(board, depth=3, alpha=-100000, beta=100000, player=True)
```

However, when running the minimax function, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-10-9ddb4749c86c>", line 64, in <module>
    minimax(board, depth=3, alpha=-100000, beta=100000, player=True)
  File "<ipython-input-10-9ddb4749c86c>", line 44, in minimax
    value, bestMove = minimax(tempBoard, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I do not understand why this occurs or how to resolve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Please provide the complete trace. Thanks!

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but trace?

Comment: thx - trace added

Comment: `return print('Game complete')` isn't going to return anything useful.

Comment: agree - very little thought when into that and it needs changing. but i don't think it's the source of the problem

Comment: Thats not the error. You are breaking from the for loop when the condition is met. After that, there is no return statement. So it returns None. What are you trying to do. Under what conditions do you want to return values?

Comment: What do you want to do with `if beta <= alpha: break`? What happens if you break out of the loop. Do you want to return something ? That needs to be figured out

Comment: To clarify what @user3386109 said. thats also an error. example: xyz = print ('abc'). Now print (xyz). You will get None. In your statement you have return print ('whatever'). That's giving you back return None which is returned from your minimax function. Hope that helps you understand the comment around return print ()

Comment: Yep i get it and have modified that part. Given it's not the source of the error I'm seeing atm, I was hoping we could avoid focussing on it.

Comment: What is if game complete? You need to return mate score and None as move if you find mate.

Comment: haven't written that bit yet (but it sounds straightforward), trying to solve current problem first.

Comment: at the bottom of your `minimax(...)` function you should do something similar to `return boardEval(tempBoard), bestMove` in order to have a proper return value when the loop stops at the break statements. Because your code currently returns `None` which causes the error.

Comment: @areop-enap, no that is wrong. user3725021, according to your error you are getting the None-value as return from your minimax. You try to unpack this None value to value, bestMove = minimax(tempBoard, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False) which is not possible. I would also suggest going for Negamax which will reduce complexity and search for bugs much more easy.

Comment: @eligolf well `boardEval(tempBoard)` should create a temporary board instance to not have none here because `minimax(...)` returns just nothing in the break case. Even no tuple.

Comment: @areop-enap, the problem is that there is nothing returned when gameComplete option happens. It should return the mate/draw scores there, now it returns None. The alpha/beta breaks should not return anything, just break the loop to not look at any more nodes in that current gamestate.

Comment: @eligolf yes, but then he will end forever with the exception because: after the break it returns no list and then tries to unpack list values, so I am not wrong of course. Just mentioning that the function `minimax(...)` has to return a proper list with 2 elements in it at the end. This happens when the for loop of minimax breaks at the `break` statement. It does not reach the `Game completed` because the recursion of minimax stops at the breaks, then it tries to unpack before the end game if question is reached and quits out because it can't unpack `None`. That's what I got from the code...

Comment: @areop-enap No that is not how minimax works. I have created many chess engines, and also in the pseudo code of minimax/negamax there is no return at the end of the function. This is because minimax is a depth first algorithm which will first go to the bottom depth of a line until it reaches depth == 0 or gameover (win/draw/loss). So it will always get a value before reaching the break statement, it only breaks if the found value can't be better in any other node.

Comment: @eligolf Should it print 'Game completed' before the error then ? either user3725021 didn't provide the full output or the unpacking fails somewhere else beside the break.

Comment: @eligolf I digged deeper into this algorithm. The break never seems to be executed. The whole if-questioning around the break actually does nothing usefull at all. So I was wrong at the point that this is causing the error. It would only bother if user wants to perform a final move for his chess AI. All minimax chess functions I know are only returning a value and no move. The final move is calculated at root level there. In this case it is fine to return nothing which is zero by default. But if user wants to perform a move at all, he has to return a tuple at minimax bottom AND at game over.